# parse from pdsh format

Tags: python, regex, format

I have to write a script which will take input for hostnames at commandline. however, user inputs the hostnames in pdsh format.
is there any simpler way to parse and extract the hostnames from the pdsh format provided.

```
example for pdsh format:
myhost[01-03]
it means we are referring hostnames - "myhost01", "myhost02" and "myhost03"
```

i need to extract the hostnames as mentioned above which i will be using later in the script.
I believe this can be done using regex which may be slightly clumsy. but is there any simpler way to do it in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do like this,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'myhost[01-03]'
>>> k, num1, num2 = re.search(r'(.+?)\[(\d+)-(\d+)', s).groups() # Gets the first word, first number, second number and stores it to their respective variables
>>> [k + '{0:02d}'.format(i) for i in range(int(num1), int(num2)+1)] # format function here is used to pad zeros if there is only one digit exists.
['myhost01', 'myhost02', 'myhost03']
```

You may define it as a separate function.

```
>>> def get_host(s):
    k, num1, num2 = re.search(r'(.+?)\[(\d+)-(\d+)', s).groups()
    return [k + '{0:02d}'.format(i) for i in range(int(num1), int(num2)+1)]

>>> print get_host('myhost[01-13]')
['myhost01', 'myhost02', 'myhost03', 'myhost04', 'myhost05', 'myhost06', 'myhost07', 'myhost08', 'myhost09', 'myhost10', 'myhost11', 'myhost12', 'myhost13']
>>>
```

Comment: It worked well. however when i pass a host name format starting with 0, it returns a wrong result. example : when i pass myhost[0300-0305], it returns ['myhost300', 'myhost301', 'myhost302', 'myhost303', 'myhost304', 'myhost305'] ignoring the 0.  
is there a way to accommodate such formats in the above code.?

Comment: `k, x, num1, y, num2 = re.search(r'(.+?)\[(0*)(\d+)-(0*)(\d+)', s).groups()`

Comment: `return [k + x + '{0:02d}'.format(i) for i in range(int(num1), int(num2)+1)]`